# Angular 13 not showing "Lazy Chunk Files" when "ng serve"

Tags: angular-cli

*Angular CLI: 13.3.7 | Angular: 13.3.11*

I'm learning Angular, and just built a lazy module, I can see it works watching the Network tab in the browser, but in the cli my "ng serve text" is different than other examples because it doesn't show the "Lazy Chunk Files" section:

```
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names   | Raw Size
main.js             | main    | 66.30 kB |
runtime.js          | runtime | 12.64 kB |

4 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2022-06-25T19:00:02.364Z - Hash: b8c52f9db784f32e - Time: 842ms

√ Compiled successfully.
```

If I comment the lazy module, then it says "3 unchanged chunks" instead of "4 unchanged chunks", so I think the cli knows my lazy module is there but... maybe there is an angular.json option that is missing or something?

And I'm not being able to find any solution to this specific issue anywhere on internet.

I want to see something like this:
[Image found on internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfdGS.png)

Comment: The image you show is after a build ng build, while you are doing ng serve

Comment: You have at the running ng serve, after it is skipping, showing only modifications to the chunks, no names

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the image is from ng build, my bad. 
And yeah, now I can see that the "Lazy Chunk Files" section is shown only at the beginning of ng serve, but not at posterior compiles.

Comment: Then, that's the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The "Lazy Chunk Files" section is shown only at the beginning of ng serve, but not at posterior compiles.